# Построение Google Chart по вызову через кнопку в jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chart

Добрый день.

Пожалуйста подскажите, почему этот код работает:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});

    function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['месяц', '', ''],
      ['1',  63, 17 ],
      ['2',  75, 33 ],
      ['3',  87, 49 ],
      ['4',  98, 65 ],
      ['5',  110, 80 ],
      ['6',  121, 95 ],
      ['7',  132, 109 ],
      ['8',  142, 123 ],
      ['9',  152, 137 ],
      ['10',  162, 151 ],
      ['11',  172, 164 ],
      ['',  ,  ,]
    ]);
   // Create and draw the visualization.
    new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('perepalata_grafic')).

        draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                    title:"График"
                }
            );
   }
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
```

а этот, в котором google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization); вызывается через действие после нажатия кнопки, не хочет работать:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});

    function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['месяц', '', ''],
      ['1',  63, 17 ],
      ['2',  75, 33 ],
      ['3',  87, 49 ],
      ['4',  98, 65 ],
      ['5',  110, 80 ],
      ['6',  121, 95 ],
      ['7',  132, 109 ],
      ['8',  142, 123 ],
      ['9',  152, 137 ],
      ['10',  162, 151 ],
      ['11',  172, 164 ],
      ['',  ,  ,]
    ]);
   // Create and draw the visualization.
    new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('perepalata_grafic')).

        draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                    title:"График"
                }
            );
   }

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#btn1").click(function(){
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
 });
</script>
```